# opencv function seqInsertSlice throwing exception with vector<Point>* array

Tags: opencv

```
    vector<vector<Point>> contourPoints;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours(canny_output, contourPoints, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
vector<Point> offsetContourPoints = contourPoints.at(0);

CvMemStorage* memStore = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* seq1 = cvCreateSeq(CV_SEQ_FLAG_SIMPLE, sizeof(CvSeq), sizeof(cv::Point), memStore);
cv::seqInsertSlice(seq1, 0, &offsetContourPoints);
```

As per my understanding seqInsertSlice has to be given an array pointer of whatever type it was declared with. In my case CvSeq holds cv::Point, thus I gave a pointer to vector. But cv::SeqInsertSlice is throwing a run time exception.

Thanks in advance

Comment: the whole 2nd part of your code is from the deprecated c-api, and should no more be used.

Comment: Yes it is a part of c-api, but as far as I know there is no proper alternative to cv::seqInsertSlice in c++ api. It takes CvSeq* as parameter which comes from c-api.

Comment: you already got a : `vector<vector<Point>> contourPoints;` just use it appropriatyry to the c++ api